# Javascript: how to get text nodes following/preceding break tags and wrap them with ddb tag?

Tags: javascript

I have accomplished this in Jquery but would like an implementation in Javascript without dependence on any libraries.

```
$("br",document).parent().contents().each(function() {
    var text = this.textContent ? this.textContent : this.innerText;
    text = this.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, '')
    if ( this.nodeType == 3 && text.length != 0) {
        $(this).wrap('<ddb></ddb>')
    }
});
```

Comment: DOM Manipulation cross browser can get nasty. Is there a particular reason you can't use jQuery?

Comment: @TelegramSam, yes Firefox xpath doesn't recognize /text() so I resort to this. Javascript will only be run on firefox, no other brorwsers, so cross browser compatibility is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the exact same thing as your function does.

```
<html>

<body>
Hello
<p>
Hello
<br/>
Hello 2
<br/>

     <br/>      
<br/>
</p>

<button onclick="wrapText()">Wrap</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function wrapText() {
        var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('br');
        for (var i=0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
            var node = nodeList[i];
            var parentNode = node.parentNode;
            if (!parentNode) continue;
            for (var c=0; c < parentNode.childNodes.length; c++) {
                var child = parentNode.childNodes[c];
                if (child.nodeType != 3) continue;

                if (child.nodeValue.match(/[^\s]/) != null) {
                    var newElement = document.createElement("b");
                    newElement.innerHTML = child.nodeValue;
                    parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, child);
                    parentNode.removeChild(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I should point out that if the `<br/>` is wrapped in any element, you are only getting the childNodes of *that* element, so if it was a simple `<b>` tag you would only wrap text nodes inside the `<b>` with `<ddb></ddb>` (what is that, by the way?).

You also had a bug that you were assigning `text` to `node.textContent ? node.textContent : node.innerText` but then the next line simply used `node.textContent`, so I fixed that.  I also changed the regex to simply match the first non-whitespace character, and if it did find one, it wrapped it.

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo I think something happened when I edited. Fixed, anyway, thanks.

Comment: I've tested this but it doesn't seem to be wrrapping the ddb tags.

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo I've replaced the code with the full test page I used.  It works for me in Firefox 3.6.  You'll notice it wraps the text with a `<b>` instead so you can see that it did something.

Comment: There's quite a few things here I'd change. First, `textContent` and `innerText` are the wrong properties for obtaining the text of a text node. Use either `data` or `nodeValue`; they are equivalent and supported in all browsers. Second, `for...in` is not guaranteed to work on a host object like a `NodeList`, so use a normal a normal `for` loop for iterating over `childNodes`. Third, avoid using `innerHTML` to populate your new node; it will be parsed as HTML when it should be treated as text. Use `newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));` instead.

Comment: @Tim Down Thanks, good points.  I considered the innerHTML part, but since the text itself is pulled from a text node (which is generated by the HTML parser in the first place), there's little (no?) chance it could be HTML. Both points brings up another point, though, which is that text inside descendant nodes (siblings to the `<br>`) will not be wrapped in the tag (as may be desired).  I've implemented the `for..` and `nodeValue` changes.

Comment: @Renesis: Regarding the innerHTML issue, you could quite easily have a text node with HTML in. For example, your original HTML could be `<p>Wow! &lt;blink&gt;Look at this!&lt;/blink&gt;</p>` and then the text node within that <p> will have a nodeValue of `"Wow! <blink>Look at this!</blink>"`.