# WebDriver: executeScript() causes BindException

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver

`javascripthere` is the script found at [Javascript: how to get text nodes following/preceding break tags and wrap them with ddb tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328724/javascript-how-to-get-text-nodes-following-preceding-break-tags-and-wrap-them-wi)

while running `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javascripthere)` on each page loaded via WebDriver,

I get the following error after the test runs for 3 minutes:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1',
java.version: '1.6.0_18'
Driver info: driver.version: remote
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:
341)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:
234)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:
173)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:
231)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$6.findElements(By.java:200)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:
158)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at
org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:
123)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:
133)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:
149)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:
108)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:
415)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:
641)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:
211)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:
125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:341)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:
328)
        ... 11 more
```

Basically the purpose of this is to capture the text nodes which cannot be selected by the `text()` xpath syntax. The Javascript wraps the text nodes before and after break tags with `<ddb>` tag. Then, WebDriver is able to get the text by using `/ddb` as xpath syntax.

Things seemingly run smoothly but crashes with the BindException error after exactly 3 minutes. It seems that the Javascript in my previous question is causing too many outbound connections.

I need a solution to allow Javascript to continually edit the DOM in WebDriver so  that text nodes is selectable by FirefoxDriver.

Comment: Is this still a problem with 1.0b release? It appears so. I get this address is already in use quite a lot. I am running this on a remote machine, which my company controls, and I don't have the ability to increase the available ports. Even if I did it seems this is a problem that shouldn't be covered up by increasing num of ports webdriver can use.

Comment: not sure but it seems its a windows problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem that seems to have been cleared up by recent changes (28 Oct 2010). It was an issue with over-exhausting the amount of ephemeral ports by either the client talking to the selenium server or even the client talking to Firefox, locally or remotely. You should update your framework (client and server side, if applicable) to the [newest release](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) (alpha-7). If you're not in a position to upgrade, you can simply increase the number of ephemeral ports locally. For Windows, the fix is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271), otherwise, do some googling.

Issue: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=923

Fix: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=10082

Comment: this problem still occurs in alpha 7 release.

Comment: Ok, it looked as if it made it to the release from browsing it on google code, but I guess that's not the case. Did you try increasing the number of local ephemeral ports? That should serve as a stopgap until they implement keep-alive connections.

Comment: yeah I guess that is the only way. Another possible solution people mentioned was running the tests on linux environment. It still causes whole bunch of TCIP ports to be open but linux is more tolerating.