# org.openqa.selenium.webelement to org.w3c.dom.domelement?

Tags: java, dom, webdriver

Is it possible to convert webdriver/selenium's `org.openqa.selenium.webelement` to `org.w3c.dom.domelement`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible given the architecture of the library. It is not guaranteed that any particular browser will expose its elements directly to the driver. However, you can pass a WebElement object as an argument to a JavaScript function via WebDriver.executeScript(). This would allow you to get to the W3C DOM element attributes and methods via JavaScript.

Comment: hi Jim, I have used executeScript() but seems like it's lot of overhead to be running on each page loaded (for my case, I had to normalize the html to a specific format for all loaded page to take care of text nodes etc). Therefore, I am staying away from any Javascript dependence.

Comment: The overhead actually isn't that much, depending on what you want to do. More context might be helpful. I'll let you in on a little secret: most of the WebDriver functionality for most drivers is implemented in JavaScript anyway. Sorry it's not the answer you wanted to hear, but the answer to your question (as asked) is still, "No, you can't convert WebElement to org.w3c.dom.Element." I was simply trying to provide you with a workaround to at least get you the functionality you wanted.

Comment: Hi Jim! Finally, a core contributer on SO! thank you for that insight you just saved me a months of work, I will pursue Javascript approach once more. Is there a wiki page explaining more about how Javacript plays a role in WebDriver functionality. So basically browser.findElement(By.id("menu")) is really browser.executeScript(document.findElementById("menu"))?

Comment: I reported some bugs with `executeScript()` on windows os in fall 2010. This isn't reproduced in linux but basically, too many ports are opened every time `executeScript()` runs (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330459/webdriver-executescript-causes-bindexception). Contextwise, I am running tests on 25 firefox webdriver instances, which clicks on everything and etc. I realized that text nodes in firefox are not selectable via By.xpath....so I had to run `executeScript("javascriptFunctionToModifyTextNodescurrentDOMpage()");` on `NavigationFinished` event.

Comment: Also, in response to :"Any #selenium #webdriver element location achievable only by using XPath should make us consider an API change." I have been worried about this for over the past two years and couldn't select the element without xpath on some DOM pages.anyways, thank you for reading my long comments...I am just excited to be back working on my project again with Javascript to find and select elements on Firefox Webdriver instance, nstead relying on org.openqa.selenium.webelement....I've avoided using `executeScript()` on each page that is loaded on webdriver ff instance fear of overhead.

Comment: But from what I understand, because Webdriver functionality relies on Javascript being executed inside the Webdriver driver instance, this should be the natural path of least resistance? For example, would there be a overhead or inefficiencies, if you were to do a recursive crawl of a domain using WebDriver instance, and you ran `executeScript("jsHighlightAllAnchorsOnPageRedColor()");` everytime a  page finished loading? is there a Navigation Listener in webdriver, so I can be notified when the page has finished loading so I can run `executeScript()`?

Comment: Also, how do I contribute some code to Webdriver ? Wish to give back what I benefited to the community....

Comment: The wiki page describing the use of JavaScript in WebDriver commands is [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AutomationAtoms). There is no "Navigation Listener"; please see [this question](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_fails_to_find_elements_/_Does_not_block_on_page_loads) in the FAQ for why. If you have code to contribute that fixes specific issues, attach a patch to the issue, and optionally notify the [selenium-developers list](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers). You might also check out the #selenium IRC channel on freenode.net